# Angularjs: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am getting error while make get request to web api using angularjs. can any comment on this.

```
$scope.getSelections = function () {
                    var user = ($scope.userInfo.userName).toString();
                    selectionsaveSrv.getSelections(user).then(function (data) {
                        var data = data;
                    });
                }
```

service:

```
function selectionsaveservice(appConfig, $q, fSrv, localStorageService, adalAuthenticationService, $http) {


getSelections = function (user) {
    var user = user;
    var webApiuri = appConfig.webApiUri + '/UserPreferences/GetSelections';
    $http.get(webApiuri, { params: { UserName: user } }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        return data;
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    });
}

return { getSelections: getSelections }
```

}

Comment: I think `success` and `error` method of `$http` service was removed from angular in version 1.2.x. Replace those with `then` method.

Answer (score 1):

As per angular documentation. Success and error methods are no longer available. These methods are depreciated instead they recommend to use standard **`.then`** method.

Change the **`getSelections`**  method inside your service as follows,

```
getSelections = function (user) {
    var user = user;
    var webApiuri = appConfig.webApiUri + '/UserPreferences/GetSelections';    
    $http.get(webApiuri, { params: { UserName: user } }).
    .then(function(response){
         if(response.status === 200) {
             return response.data;
         }
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.. the core problem was getSelections function wasn't returning promise..

Answer (score 1):

As error clearly stated that *Cannot read property 'then' of undefined*, the cause behind the error is `.then` method does available on `promise` object and you're expecting to get promise from `getSelections` method. By returning promise from `getSelections` method should fix your problem.

```
getSelections = function (user) {
    var user = user;
    var webApiuri = appConfig.webApiUri + '/UserPreferences/GetSelections';
    return $http.get(webApiuri, { params: { UserName: user } });
}
```

> **Note:** Don't use `success` and `error` callback, as they're deprecated